# How to use Shell32 within a C# application?

Tags: c#, shell32

What should I include within a C# application in order to make Shell32 work?

**Edit:**

My application can't recognize shell32. What references or lib should I  include? What I'm trying to do is:

```
Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.Shell();
```

What I'm getting as an error:

> Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Shell32' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.Shell();
Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Shell32' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use an external library. Shell32 is not a standard component of .NET framework. Have you copied the sample from somewhere?

Comment: @David I believe what OP is looking for is "what using statements are required..." @Shaza, if this is correct you need to look at P/Invoke. Shell32 is a invoked using reflection as an unmanaged .dll. More can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133703/referencing-shell32-again-c-visual-studio

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Just add a reference to `Shell32.dll` from the `Windows\System32` folder and use it:

```
Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.Shell();
shell.MinimizeAll();
```

Comment: I am using 64 bit OS and buiding app as x86, so should I take reference from same Windows/system32 or from "C:\Windows\SysWOW64".

Shell32.dll size is diff in both folder.

Comment: You can also add a reference to *Microsoft Shell controls and Automation* from the COM tab in the *Reference Manager* (*Add Reference* Dialog Window) in Visual Studio 2010 and above... not sure which earlier versions have this though.

Comment: @Sheridan:  My "Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation" reports it is Version 1.0 from Windows 7 SP1.  So I assume this is at least available as far back as Win7 SP1.

Comment: @JoeB _Windows 10 Creator Update_ here, still version 1.0

Comment: Adding a reference to _Microsoft Shell controls and Automation_ is equivalent to adding _shell32.dll_ from "Windows\System32". The resulting reference is the same and contains only the Guid of the DLL.

Answer (score 63):

maybe this can help:

1. Right click project
2. Click `Add reference`
3. Click `.COM` tab in `Add reference` dialogue
4. Select `Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation`
5. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>

your `shell32` is ready to use...

Answer (score 32):

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5708578/) does not compile under windows 8 and later. For that, a workaround can be found [here](http://techitongue.blogspot.com/2012/06/shell32-code-compiled-on-windows-7.html):

```
using Shell32;

private Shell32.Folder GetShell32Folder(string folderPath)
{
    Type shellAppType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application");
    Object shell = Activator.CreateInstance(shellAppType);
    return (Shell32.Folder)shellAppType.InvokeMember("NameSpace",
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, shell, new object[] { folderPath });
}
```

Answer (score 8):

1. Right click your project in the solution explorer.
2. Choose "Add Reference..." from the drop-down menu.
3. Click the "Browse" tab.
4. Navigate to the `C:\Windows\System32` directory.
5. Choose the `shell32.dll` file. and press the "OK" button.

You now have the appropriate reference for using `Shell32.Shell`.

Answer (score 5):

Add to your project a reference to the COM library **Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation**. Additionally, ensure that the code using `Shell32.Shell` is running in a single threaded apartment, e.g. by adding the `[STAThread]` attribute to `Main`.

Answer (score 2):

The class shown below should help with some of the methods of shell32 in C# .
you should add the reference of "Microsoft Shell command and automation" with the reference window by righting clicking the project .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

    namespace MusicMuttPrototype
    {
        public class clsShellFileInfo
        {
            public Exception errorException;
            public enum FileDetailInfo
            {
                Name = 0,
                Year = 15,
                Size = 1,
                Track_Number = 19,
                Type = 2,
                Genre = 20,
                Date_Modified = 3,
                Duration = 27,
                Date_Created = 4,
                Bit_Rate = 28,
                Date_Accessed = 5,
                Protected = 23,
                Attributes = 6,
                Camera_Model = 24,
                Status = 7,
                Date_Picture_Taken = 25,
                Owner = 8,
                Dimensions = 26,
                Author = 9,
                Not_used = 27,
                Title = 10,
                Not_used_file = 28,
                Subject = 11,
                //Not_used = 29,
                Category = 12,
                Company = 30,
                Pages = 13,
                Description = 31,
                Comments = 14,
                File_Version = 32,
                Copyright = 15,
                Product_Name_Chapter = 33,
                //Scripting Quicktest Profess11ional Page 63 
                Artist = 16,
                Product_Version = 34,
                Album_Title = 17,
                Retrieves_the_info_tip_inf = -1
            }

            public string getFileDetails(string fileFolder, string filePath, FileDetailInfo infotype)
            {
                string strReturnval = "";
                try
                {
                    Shell32.Shell fileshell = new Shell32.Shell();
                    Shell32.Folder fileshellfolder = fileshell.NameSpace(fileFolder);
                    Shell32.FolderItem Item = fileshellfolder.ParseName(filePath);
                    strReturnval = fileshellfolder.GetDetailsOf(Item, (int)infotype);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    errorException = ex;
                }
                return strReturnval;
            }


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the full set of API calls, you maybe better off creating a COM import stub class. See how Mike Ward who wrote Desk Drive did it.

[Link 1](http://mike-ward.net/2008/09/02/a-lean-method-for-invoking-com-in-c/)

[Link 2](https://github.com/mike-ward/DeskDrive/blob/master/src/DeskDrive/Shell32.cs)

Comment: i like this. i found a msdn tutorial on this, and a ms tool to generate them. the page is called: "COM Interop Part 1: C# Client Tutorial", in case my link breaks. and here is the link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa645736%28v=vs.94%29?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1):

C# .Net
I do not understand the full question but this is working for me.

```
[DllImport("Shell32.dll")]
        public static extern int ShellExecuteA(int hwnd, string lpOperation, string lpFile, int lpParameters, int lpDirecotry, int nShowCmd);

private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int open;
            open = ShellExecuteA(0, "open", "https://google.com", 0, 0, 1);
        }
```

Using a picturebox to open a link.