# C# - new Shell32() throw an exception?

Tags: c#, shell32, shell32.dll

I need to use Shell32 in my C# application to create a lnk file.

I added shell32.dll to my references and tried to compile this single code line:

```
Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.Shell();
```

and I got an `InvalidCastException`!

the error code : 'HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).'

How should I use Shell32.Shell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Shell32 within a C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708434/how-to-use-shell32-within-a-c-sharp-application)

Comment: I already added the reference. It just won't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023191/invalidcastexception-was-unhandled

Comment: I still need to get the `Shell` object.

Comment: Are you calling it from a MTA thread rather than an STA thread by any chance? It must be called from an STA thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank You, I've found the way with your comments.
I just need to use this as `dynamic`.

```
static readonly Guid CLSID_Shell = Guid.Parse("13709620-C279-11CE-A49E-444553540000");
dynamic shell = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_Shell));
```

Also, If I add the `STAThreadAttribute` to my Main method it works without problems (credits goes to [@Matthew Watson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106159/matthew-watson))