# error include reference Shell32 visual studio C #

Tags: c#

I wanted them to ask a favor I'm working on a small console application in C # which is walking a folder search for videos and tell me how long it lasts and other things the matter is that when I import the reference shell32 I still generates the error as if he was not wanted such a reference and ask them how it could help solve this problem (here a catch) if they see references in Part shell32 I get a warning and not because

thank you
[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ecau.png)

[import reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCRl0.png)

Comment: You might want to post this at http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Windows 8/10, there seems to be an issue with using shell32 that way.

Check this thread for a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19035049/2709150

Comment: I have Win 8 but shell32 imported from imported system32 when I get some kind of warning references and medeja not use shell32  and I show an image above

Comment: @JhonnyLuis sorry could not understand what you are trying to say. Probably best to post the question to [http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions) as suggested by B. Clay Shannon.