# Access external card DCIM on Android phone folder from a Windows Desktop application

Tags: c#, windows

I am building a Windows Forms application using .Net 4.5.2 and I try to access the DCIM folder on external card on an Android phone. When I use Windows Explorer, the location is "Username @MachineName\Galaxy Phone Model\Card\DCIM".
How can I access this path programmatically, ideally without the need of a third party library?

Answer (score 1):

If the card is exposed as a shell folder and not a drive letter then you need to use the shell namespace.

In native code this would be [`SHParseDisplayName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shparsedisplayname) and then interact with it with `IShellFolder` and/or `IShellItem`. `IFileOperation` to copy/move/delete.

If you don't want to P/Invoke you can use the Shell.Application COM object to [parse the namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19035049/3501) of a folder path and then [copy/move/enumerate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder)...

Comment: Thanks Anders. I tried to use the Shell32 and I got to browse to the DCIM folder, but then I could not access the Camera folder. It is something more complex than what I was expecting.